# concurrent.futures errors out saying argument missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python

I have a small toy example like this

```
def hello(filename,suffix):                     
    print(filename + str(suffix))               


params = [('test.csv', 1), ('test2.csv', 2)]
ex = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)  

results = ex.map(hello, params)                 

real_results = list(results)
```

When i execute this piece of code i get an error saying

TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'suffix'

Well i thought suffix is 1 in the first thread and 2 in the second thread.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through `ex.map`, the elements from `params` will be passed as first argument to `hello`. If you want to pass multiple arguments to a threaded function, there are a few possibilities:

1. Make two argument lists, one for first arguments, one for second arguments and pass them both as argument to `exp.map`:

   ```
   params1 = ['test.csv', 'test2.csv']
   params2 = [1, 2]
   results = ex.map(hello, params1, params2)
   ```
2. Let `hello` take a single tuple of arguments and then unpack them:

   ```
   def hello(args):
       filename, suffix = args
   ```
3. Transpose and unpack the `params` list onto `ex.map` (really this is the same as 1. without manual coversion to `params1` and `params2`):

   ```
   ex.map(hello, *zip(*params))
   ```

Comment: @BlackJack Yes, fixed. Thanks for letting me know.